# Performance penalty JavaScript callback-functions

Tags: javascript, performance, callback

Is there a performance penalty when using callback functions (in JavaScript), opposed to using it in a synchronous manner?

For instance:

```
method(function(result){});
```

Instead of

```
var result = method();
```

Edit: And if there is an overhead introduced by the callback functions, I would love to know why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I made some tests with simple computation mechanism and found that asynchronous callbacks are a bit slower than the synchronous counterpart. But you should understand the reasons for what they are used and the answer is concurrency more than performance. They are slower because they pass through EVENT LOOP.

Comment: Thank you! I will edit my question, because I'm curious why there is a performance overhead.
Edit: I see you've updated your comment, with an explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thereis a teeny tiny overhead for using callback-functions in synchronous computation compared to return. 
*Yes, callbacks can be used in a synchronous way. Check out [CPS](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style); or for consistency reasons in the API.*

This overhead comes through the overhead of clling a function and maintaining the call-stack, and since you often use closures as callbacks, there is a little overhead to create them, too.

But this would be micro-optimizations, comparable to replacing a `v * 2` with `v << 1` (for performance reasons). 
If you have to optimize such things in your code, you have some really serious problems in the structure of your application.

The only problem to be mentioned when calling callbacks synchronously, is the possibility to exceed the maximum stack-size at some point.

Comment: Small note:
This question has arised from my curiosity. It is not derived from poor programming skills :D. And thank you for your contribution!

Comment: I didn't imply poor programming skills. I just tried to cover the whole topic for everyone that reads this answer.